# What is the best way to measure goodness of fit between data and functions?

Tags: regression, medicine

I am not that familiar with statistics and was wondering about the best way to quantify the difference between a set of data and a function.

My scenario is that I have a set with maximum heart rate data from around 60 people, with their age. I'm trying to see which of all "mathematical models" out there that describe the relation between maximum heart rate and age, is the least wrong.

I'm much better at understanding the biology behind this, not the mathematics.

Comment: @Filip, Perhaps you want to just plot the data you have vs the data that is predicted by the models, and look for the error(norm) between the two sets of data. The one with the least error is the "best" model. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)

Comment: Is your model linear or nonlinear? For linear models (where the free parameters are coefficients multiplying functions like $y=a+bx$ or $y=c+d\exp(x)+f\exp(2x)$), there is the coefficient of determination $R^2$ that you can use as the starting point, which has a similar purpose to Pearson's correlation coefficient for general linear models (the nearer to 1, the more likely the fit is good). Alternatively, you can take the sum of squares of residuals $\chi^2=\sum_i(y_i-f(x_i))^2$ (i.e. picakhu's suggestion).

Comment: @Picakhu: Thank you. I have implemented that for the time being.
@J.M.: It's a mix of both linear models and exponential models. And I don't have one X-value for every Y-value along the spectra (for example i don't have any 32 year old testperson). Any other method you can recommend? 
@JasonMond:Aah. Is there any way to move my post there, or is it best practice to create a new one?

Comment: @Filip, I'm migrating this for you.

Comment: @Filip, think not only of identifying the least wrong model, but characterizing where your preferred model fits best, and where it fits worst.  I strongly recommend plotting the data and function as others have recommended.